# Issues when cross compiling helloworld Windows executable on Linux with Clang / OLLVM

Tags: c++, llvm-clang

I am having issues compiling a Windows application with Clang / OLLVM on a Linux/Ubuntu system, I know I "could" use other tools for this (MinGW etc...) but I want to do it this way because I want to use obfuscation which is provided by OLLVM. However I have the feeling that Clang/LLVM has very light documentation in regards to cross-compilation (compiling Windows executables on a Linux system) and that setting things up correctly is some kind of black magic :-(.

I have built this project:

https://github.com/qtfreet00/llvm-obfuscator

And I have done the following and to be very honest, I do not understand what most of these flags actually mean, since some appear to be completely un-documented:

https://nosubstance.me/post/coding-windows-cpp-on-linux/

And I seem to have reached a dead-end (had issues with case-sensitivity includes using <> instead of "" which I fixed etc...) but now I am stuck on something which appears fairly trivial to solve. When I try to build using the following flags:

```
/home/puss/dev/clang-llvm-build/bin/clang -isystem "/home/puss/dev/ewdk/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.19041.0/km/crt" -isystem "/home/puss/dev/ewdk-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.19041.0/shared" -isystem "/home/puss/dev/ewdk-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.19041.0/ucrt" -isystem "/home/puss/dev/ewdk-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.19041.0/um" -isystem "/home/puss/dev/msf-http-stager/header" -target i386-pc-windows-msvc -x c++ -fsyntax-only -ferror-limit=64 -fms-compatibility-version=19 -Wno-everything -Wno-unknown-pragmas -U__clang__ -U__clang_version__ -U__clang_major__ -U__clang_minor__ -U__clang_patchlevel__ -fms-extensions -std=c++14 -mllvm -bcf -x c++ -c /tmp/hello.cpp -o hello.o
```

my hello.cpp file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
/tmp/hello.cpp:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I do have the iostream header here, which should be known to the compiler because I specified it using a -isystem flag pointing to it:

```
/home/puss/dev/ewdk/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.19041.0/km/crt/iostream
```

As it seems my issue is similar to this one:

https://github.com/JuliaInterop/Cxx.jl/issues/114

Any ideas as to what is going on here ? I also tried pulling the exact same EWDK as described here:

https://nosubstance.me/post/coding-windows-cpp-on-linux/

but when I run this on my hello.cpp file:

```
#!/bin/sh

/home/william/dev/clang-llvm-build/bin/clang -x c++ \
    --target=i386-pc-windows-msvc \
    -fsyntax-only \
    -ferror-limit=64 \
    -fms-compatibility-version=19 \
    -Wall \
    -Wextra \
    -Wno-unknown-pragmas \
    -U__clang__ \
    -U__clang_version__ \
    -U__clang_major__ \
    -U__clang_minor__ \
    -U__clang_patchlevel__ \
    -DWIN32 \
    -D_WINDOWS \
    -DNDEBUG \
    -D_MT \
    -D_X86_=1 \
    -DNOMINMAX \
    -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 \
    -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN=1 \
    -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS=1 \
    -nostdinc \
    -isystem '/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.15063.0/shared' \
    -isystem '/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.15063.0/ucrt' \
    -isystem '/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.15063.0/um' \
    -isystem '/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/microsoft visual studio 14.0/vc/include' \
    -isystem '/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.15063.0/km/crt' \
    -c '/tmp/hello.cpp' -o 'hello.obj'
```

I also get errors relating to 'std':

```
/tmp/hello.cpp:4:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'std'
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    ^
1 error generated.
```

On weird thing though is that the `iostream.h` header is in here ("km"):

```
'/home/william/dev/ewdk1703-insensitive/program files/windows kits/10/include/10.0.15063.0/km/crt'
```

Which seems to relate more to Kernel drivers than user-mode applications.

Comment: `#pragma once`.  Does this work with your compiler?  If not, use traditional `#include` guards, i.e. `#ifndef HEADER_FILE_NAME_H #define HEADER_FILE_NAME_H...#endif`

Comment: Yes, Clang does support #pragma once (Wikipedia says so :-) )

Comment: The way you whittle this problem down is to use divide-and-conquer.  Comment out everything from `stager.cpp` (yes, everything).  If it compiles with no errors, introduce a header at a time, compile.  Once you get to the stage when the compilation breaks down, then you know that the combination of files you are using is causing an issue in some way.

Comment: It broke as soon as I uncomment the : 

#include "http_requests.h"

Which contains the following:

#pragma once
#include <string>

void HttpRequest(std::string site, std::string param, std::string ua, int Port, std::string method, char* buf);

Comment: So now comment the `#include "http_requests.h"` file again, and simply add this line in stager.cpp:  `void HttpRequest(std::string site, std::string param, std::string ua, int Port, std::string method, char* buf);`  -- So basically you should have everything compiling, and when that line in `stager.cpp` is seen by the compiler, you should get errors.  If you do not get errors, then something inside of `http_requests.h` is faulty.  This is the trial and error approach in solving the problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I tried that, I now have the exact same compiler errors but all in stager.cpp.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to fix the issue, it seems that it was an issue of using:

```
<iostream> vs <iostream.h>
```